# How to add radio function to Bootstrap button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 2 has a `data-toggle` attribute which can be set as `buttons-radio` like :

```
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
   <button id="1" class="btn">One</button>
   <button id="2" class="btn">Two</button>
   <button id="3" class="btn">Three</button>
  </div>
```

Now I need to have same functionality in button groups with Bootstrap 3. How can I toggle active class between buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very similar functionality in Bootstrap 3

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Example here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples